# SQL 2008 Backups writing to event log

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a maintenace plan settup to take transaction log backups every 15 minutes. Well everytime it does so, it writes a message to the windows event log. How can I disable this? I looked through the maintenance plan configuration and the Agent Job it created and can't see how to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable successful backup event logging by enabling [**Trace Flag 3226**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx)

To set this persistently add `-T 3226` to the Startup Parameters option of the server instance in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

- Start Config Manager, click on SQL Server Services
- Right-Click on your server instance (default instance is `SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER)`)
- Click the Advanced tab
- Add `-T 3226` to the string in the Startup Parameters option
- Restart your server instance